# solving cyclic dependency with python inheritance

Tags: python, oop, circular-dependency, state-pattern

Using the OOP 'State' pattern in python leaded me to this dependency problem:
`StateA`, `StateB`and `StateC` are 3 states implementing the same method `event1`.
`StateB` inherits its behavior from `StateA`.

*file a.py*:

```
#from b import StateB
from c import StateC

class StateA(object):
    def event1(self):
        return StateC()

print type(StateA().event1())
```

*file b.py:*

```
import a
class StateB(a.StateA):
    def event1(self):
        return self
```

*file c.py:*

```
class StateC(object):
    def event1(self):
        return self
```

As long as I don't need `StateB` in `a.py`, this works. But what if I want to use type `StateB` in `StateA`?
Importing `StateB` (see the first commented line in `a.py`) leads to this cyclic dependency error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name StateB
```

Comment: You can try doing a local import (inside some specific method) instead of importing it at the top of the file.

Comment: what happens if you change the global import on file b?

Comment: same error if I move the global import on file b inside method StateA.event1()

Answer (score 2):

Circle dependencies is a problem connected with code design. In practice, you could meet that probably only in badly organized code. Try to refactor your code to resolve this issue.

Another approach (which I not suggest you to do, just FYI) is an import outside of module-level import, but you should avoid such an approach.

Comment: cyclic dependency is often required when applying the 'State' pattern, because loops of transitions may exist between states.

Answer (score 1):

Since your classes are tightly coupled, I would just put them into the same module:

*file my_state.py*:

```
class StateA(object):
    def event1(self):
        return StateC()


class StateB(StateA):
    def event1(self):
        return self


class StateC(object):
    def event1(self):
        return self


print(type(StateA().event1()))
```

Comment: that would certainly help, but my actual classes are much bigger and I would like to keep them in separate files if possible.

Comment: If they are that big, then you probably need to split them up and extract some functions / classes which could then be placed into separate module(s).